# Возможный конфликт роутера единой точки входа MVC и роутера frond-end'a

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, vue.js

Всем привет. Делаю Front-end на Vue.js, Back-end весь на php написан. Возникли вопросы, которые ставят меня в тупик:

- Php работает по принципу единой точки входа, все запросы на index.php, оттуда инициируется класс Router.php и запрос переходит на нужный контроллер через routes.php, ничего необычного. Проблема в том, что для работы на фронтенде Vue.js (нужен для грамотной реализации SPA), Vue.js необходим его компонент (Vue-Router). Vue-router также имеет свои routes или paths, где также есть путь и компонент, за него отвечающий. Что делать в такой ситуации? Сервер работает на php, все нормально, но как на него поставить Front-end Vue.js?
- Нужен ли для работы Vue-router сервер на node.js? Т.е. нужно, чтобы все URL запросы шли к Vue, где он уже будет вызывать необходимый компонент, как это сделать?
- Правильно ли я понимаю, что все общение с бэкэндом при использовании vue.js идет через ajax-запросы?

Comment: Очень хороший пример [здесь](http://blog.rimonbd.com/posts/17/Vue-js-2-%E0%A6%8F%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%82-php-and-MySQL-%E0%A6%A6%E0%A6%BF%E0%A7%9F%E0%A7%87-%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%AD%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%87-CRUD-%E0%A6%85%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%B6%E0%A6%A8-%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%A8-%3A-%E0%A6%AA%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AC--%E0%A7%A9). На бенгальском, правда (гугл сносно перевел). Много полезного для себя узнал.

Answer (score 0):

1. Frontend и backend полностью изолированы друг от друга, и общаются между собой запросами по сети в том или ином виде. Так что 0 проблем
2. Нет (см пункт 1)
3. Да. Можно еще websocket прикрутить, как вариант